# Apply styling from parent component to a specific component in child component | react, material ui, styled-components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

There are multiple components in child component and can I apply styling to a specific component that is in child component from parent component?

App/index.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, StyledMenu } from "./styles";

const App = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    <Container className={className}>
      <h1>this is a demo</h1>
      <StyledMenu />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

App/styles.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Demo from "../Demo";

export const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 20px;
`;

Container.displayName = "Container";

export const StyledMenu = styled(Demo)`
  & .MuiPaper-root {
    width: 300px;
  }
`;

StyledMenu.displayName = "StyledMenu";
```

Demo/index.jsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
// import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import { MenuDisplay } from "./styles";

export default function BasicMenu({ className }) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <Button
        id="basic-button"
        aria-controls={open ? "basic-menu" : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Dashboard
      </Button>
      <MenuDisplay
        id="basic-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          "aria-labelledby": "basic-button"
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </MenuDisplay>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo/styles.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";

export const MenuDisplay = styled(Menu)`
  background-color: green;
`;

MenuDisplay.displayName = "MenuDisplay";
```

I like to apply `width: 300px` for the `Menu` component (where it is a dropdown menu) in Demo/index.jsx from App/style.js.

Is that possible?

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-dust-6j5hce?file=/Demo/index.jsx) for demo

Here is [`Menu` component from mui doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#basic-menu)

### Attempts

I imported `MenuDisplay` (that's in Demo/styles.js) inside App/styles.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Demo from "../Demo";
import { MenuDisplay } from "../Demo/styles";

export const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 20px;
`;

Container.displayName = "Container";

export const StyledMenu = styled(Demo)`
  ${MenuDisplay} & {
    & .MuiPaper-root {
      width: 300px;
    }
  }
`;

StyledMenu.displayName = "StyledMenu";
```

This didn't work

Answer (score -1):

To apply css to your child component, define width in the Demo/styles.js

export const MenuDisplay = styled(Menu)`width: 300px;`;

For more detail see the replay https://dashboard.testwise.io/replays/bRJwLQfxEcG of your issue.

Comment: It looks straightforward my expample but the reason why I want to apply styling from parent component is that I'm passing props to child component just to apply css.

Comment: i have proposed solution considering that you don't have multiple menu's as child component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).